# sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception the status code returned from the server was 500

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, configuration

when I click on Button i want to redirect to another page (vb.net code).
Now if i am using my code in visual studio 8 , it's working fine but in visual studio 2012 it gets error in browser consol like below and cannot go into execution of vb.code.

can any one help me out to solve that thing..

```
POST http://localhost/TMS_WEB/frmEventSchedule.aspx?Mode=Planning 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5

Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.executeRequest @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
Sys.Net._WebRequestManager.executeRequest @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
Sys.Net.WebRequest.invoke @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmit @ ScriptResource.axd?d=OYcYUsN1jrZ11Zo6YGMqv2SJ0gsCQ6FsMqwFuIK_fKjp9p80ufP_-7tIq7dZFAfrKRo4W90i_wzCoq…:5
(anonymous function) @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
b @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5


XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/TMS_WEB/frmEventSchedule.aspx?Mode=Planning".
Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.executeRequest @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
Sys.Net._WebRequestManager.executeRequest @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
Sys.Net.WebRequest.invoke @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmit @ ScriptResource.axd?d=OYcYUsN1jrZ11Zo6YGMqv2SJ0gsCQ6FsMqwFuIK_fKjp9p80ufP_-7tIq7dZFAfrKRo4W90i_wzCoq…:5 
(anonymous function) @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
b @ ScriptResource.axd?d=lw0IPgH2mrygbq4_NoTZCpzyX-yoJHK8Nj5HjXTv0boIebChtGq3xm65yS8w0iAbkn8jzFKrmQahfY…:5
```

Comment: Please could you show the relevant code parts, on which the errors occur?

Answer (score 0):

I checked in my browser network status and 
It shows that Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded() +2693342
   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +61
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +148
```

search for this and find out that

in my web.config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
</appSettings>
```

change this

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="3001" />
</appSettings>
```

Thats solve my issue.

Hope this will help someone..